# Qemu-img 5.2.91 can't open vmdk, Failed to lock byte 100: Input/output error, but qemu-img 2.5 work

Tags: qemu, vmdk

```
openstack:~/qemu-6.0.0-rc1/build$ qemu-img --version
qemu-img version 2.5.0 (Debian 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.51), Copyright (c) 2004-2008 Fabrice Bellard
openstack:~/qemu-6.0.0-rc1/build$ sudo qemu-img check /mnt/esxi/name.vmdk
No errors were found on the image.

openstack:~/qemu-6.0.0-rc1/build$ ./qemu-img -V
qemu-img version 5.2.91
Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
openstack:~/qemu-6.0.0-rc1/build$ sudo ./qemu-img check /mnt/esxi/name.vmdk
qemu-img: Could not open '/mnt/esxi/name.vmdk': Failed to lock byte 100: Input/output error
```

As the command output, the `qemu-img 5.2.91` can't check the vmdk file, but `qemu-img 2.5` works fine.

`qemu-img 5.2.91 --help` get this:

```
Supported formats: blkdebug blklogwrites blkverify bochs cloop compress copy-on-read dmg file host_cdrom host_device luks nbd null-aio null-co nvme preallocate qcow qcow2 qed quorum raw rbd replication throttle vdi vhdx vmdk vpc vvfat
```

How can I fix it? THX

[image]

Comment: I don't have a solid answer for you, but it might help to know if the vmdk file is currently in use by a VM, since the error indicates a failure to lock it. And if it IS in use, kill the VM first and try again?

Comment: The VM is shutoff, and why the old version(2.5) qemu-img check it was OK but the 5.2.91 version check it can not open?

Comment: I'm just guessing that the locking protocol was either different, or absent, in the old version

Comment: Are there any files in the same folder, or elsewhere, that have similar filenames to the vmdk, but with "lock" appended? Something like that? Perhaps a previous VM session left a stale lock file.

Comment: Maybe it not about the stale lock file.Check the picture I update the question.

Comment: The qemu-img 5.2.91 version compile from source code with the configure `./configure --enable-rbd --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.6`, is there I miss some `configure` parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231487/discussion-between-victorlee-and-aiken-drum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the vmdk file in NFS directory, add this option `-o nolock` fixed it.

`nolock — Disables file locking. This setting is occasionally required when connecting to older NFS servers. noexec — Prevents execution of binaries on mounted file systems. This is useful if the system is mounting a non-Linux file system via NFS containing incompatible binaries.`